# Is this sacrificial command a good idea?

Tags: macros, best-practices

I have this command:

```
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\edef\name{#1}}
```

You first call it as in `\name{Don}` and afterwards you can refer to Don using `\name`. **Is this an accetable way to express a constant that should be set only once?**

Comment: It might do, although I'd prefer `\setname` for setting the constant `\name`. I would definitely *not* use `\edef`, where `\def` suffices. Try `\name{G\"odel}` and see why.

Comment: @egreg `\name{G\"odel}` works fine.

Comment: With `\edef`? Try `\show\name` and see. Or `\name{\textit{Don}}` Or `\name{\t{Yu}ry}`

Comment: Do you mean "self-referential" command?

Comment: Are you sure the command will only be used once? For instance `\title` can be redefined midway, and I sometimes do it for serial documents if the class I use allows for multiple `\maketitle`. If not (and I think not), I would support the Idea of going for `\setname` to define `\name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use different commands, one to hold the name and another to set the name.

In a package, it is a common practice to use an external version of the command (`\name`) to set the value of an internal macro (`\@name`). This is how `\author` and `\title` work in the `article` class.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\gdef\@name{#1}}
\makeatother
```

But it would be clearer and simpler if you use different types of commands to indicate different behaviors. So `\name` expands to the name, and `\setname` defines the value of `\name`:

```
\newcommand{\setname}[1]{\gdef\name{#1}}
```

It's good to distinguish between commands that indicate material that will be typeset, and commands that define constants. In my opinion, the default `\author` and `\title` commands in LaTeX should really be `\setauthor` and `\settitle`, since the actual typesetting only happens when you give the command `\maketitle`.

Comment: If the value is used in the document, it should be `\name` anyway.

Comment: @egreg I hope the edit addresses your concerns. I completely agree with you. I use `\gdef` because that's what I've seen used in this case, but does it give any advantage over just `\def`?

Comment: `\gdef` and `\def` are pretty much equivalent for this, because `\setname` will be quite certainly issued at the top level; with `\gdef` you ensure definition even if `\setname` appears in a group.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, why not. Your use, your choice.

Depending on the specific application, you might consider using `\xdef` take make the (expanded) redefinition global or `\protected@xdef` to accommodate "strange constructions" in names...